# DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_HUNG resulting from concurrency::copy on C++ AMP

Tags: gpgpu, direct3d11, c++-amp

I have created some C++ AMP code for performing background gradient removal on astronomical images.  They come in as 16-bit unsigned integers for RGB.  All of my application's processing and output occurs in single precision floating point, so I convert the input data, run the C++ AMP code, and then copy the results back to the CPU (in reality the image will go through many of these C++ AMP filters on the GPU before being copied back, but for this test code I have isolated it to just a single such filter.

Everything goes well until I initiate the concurrency::copy operation to copy the data back to the CPU from the GPU array.  That operation throws an exception indicating that TDR has been triggered because of `DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_HUNG`.  The full error is:

> D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11Device::RemoveDevice: Device removal has been triggered for the following reason (DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_HUNG: The Device took an unreasonable amount of time to execute its commands, or the hardware crashed/hung. As a result, the TDR (Timeout Detection and Recovery) mechanism has been triggered. The current Device Context was executing commands when the hang occurred. The application may want to respawn and fallback to less aggressive use of the display hardware). [ EXECUTION ERROR #378: DEVICE_REMOVAL_PROCESS_AT_FAULT]

Below is the code in question.  I've omitted the filter's code since it makes it through all the filters fine (I stepped through it in the debugger) and only throws the exception when it copies back to the CPU.  The problem line is `concurrency::copy(frame, begin(cpu_frame));` in the code below:

```
array<float_3, 2> convert_input(std::vector<float_3> &output, unsigned short *input, int n, int m) {
    int o = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n * m * 3; i += 3) {
        output[o] = float_3((float)input[i] / (float)MAXUINT16, (float)input[i + 1] / (float)MAXUINT16, (float)input[i + 2] / (float)MAXUINT16);
        o++;
    }

    return array<float_3, 2>(n, m, begin(output));
}

void _stdcall remove_gradient(unsigned short *input, float *output, int n, int m)
{
    std::vector<float_3> cpu_frame(n * m);

    array<float_3, 2> frame = convert_input(cpu_frame, input, n, m);

    GradientRemovalFilter *filter = new GradientRemovalFilter();

    try {
        filter->FilterFrame(frame);

        concurrency::copy(frame, begin(cpu_frame));
    }
    catch (accelerator_view_removed &ex) {
        std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
        std::cout << ex.get_view_removed_reason() << std::endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n * m; i ++) {
        output[(i * 3)] = cpu_frame[i].r;
        output[(i * 3) + 1] = cpu_frame[i].g;
        output[(i * 3) + 2] = cpu_frame[i].b;
    }
}
```

Any idea what's going wrong and how to prevent it?  My test images are about 10,000 total pixels, so very small and much smaller than what I will be working with in reality, so I don't see why the copy back is taking long enough to cause the TDR to kick in, especially when the complicated processing and the copy to the GPU are being accomplished just fine.

Comment: In an unrelated instance, I encountered this error in a DX12 program by forgetting to set a CBV descriptor heap for the command list I'm using. The error code is also DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_HUNG but there is not a timeout. So in my case the error description does not match the actual error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error output above told you what happened: Your shader took so long the driver figured the GPU hung.

The [recommendations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nativeconcurrency/archive/2012/03/07/handling-tdrs-in-c-amp.aspx) here are:

- Break your processing into smaller chunks or simplify the compute operation
- use `D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DISABLE_GPU_TIMEOUT` with DirectX 11.1+ (see [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nativeconcurrency/archive/2012/03/01/disabling-tdr-on-windows-8-for-your-c-amp-algorithms.aspx))
- or [edit the registry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff569918(v=VS.85).aspx) to extend the timeout, which is really only useful for development.

**EDIT:** The problem is most likely in `filter->FilterFrame` which is the C++ AMP code that becomes a DirectCompute shader that is likely to be causing the TDR. The fact that the error is returned a little later is not surprising due to CPU/GPU synchronization/timing differences.

Comment: I don't believe you actually read the question.  The error is occurring on the call to concurrency::copy, not on my shader.  Are you suggesting that I break up the copy into smaller chunks?  Should that be necessary with 10,000 elements?  Certainly it can copy 10,000 floats from the gpu to the cpu in less than 2 seconds.

Comment: AMP turns your C++ into DIrectCompute shaders so I used 'shader' interchangeably with 'code'. I'm sorry for the confusion. I expect the problem is likely happening in ``filter->FilterFrame`` because it is still running when you try to perform the copy and exceeded the TDR timeout. Try the remedies I linked to and see if resolves them, or try a trivial version of ``GradientRemovalFilter``. Remember that the GPU and the CPU are not in lock step, and that many Direct3D operations will queue up and happen in batches.

Comment: Thank you, this clarification was very insightful as to the source of the problem.  I think it would be good if you could edit your answer to focus on the insight of the copy forcing a synchronization and the debugging landing on it as the "cause" being a red herring.  That would probably be the most useful information to others who run into this apparent problem in the future and I'll accept the answer.